# MySQL command line - bind <UP> key to a backward command search

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, mysql

With mysql command line client on Ubuntu 14.04 I could bind <kbd>UP</kbd> to a backward command search by adding the following lines to `~/.inputrc`

```
# type a word, hit up and a search is performed
# "\e[A": history-search-backward
```

This `inputrc` setting would be read and provide customised bindings in MySQL command line, i.e. start interactive MySQL command line:

```
% mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
Server version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)
```

Then once in I could type a word and hit <kbd>UP</kbd> and the mysql command line would perform a backward search through the command history based on the word:

```
mysql> select <UP>
```

would give results like

```
mysql> select * from user;
```

I literally had the same settings in 14.04 and they worked, now in `ubuntu 16.04` and `mysql-client-5.7` this doesn't work, instead I simply get the default behaviour of showing previous commands in chronological order.
How can I get the <kbd>UP</kbd> key to perform a command history search in mysql command line?

Comment: Does this work in other programs that use readline, such as bash and `rlwrap`?

Comment: @Gilles I believe so. an SQLite prompt seems to read my ~/.inputrc. I discovered that this version of MySQL 5.7.x is compiled using editline library - Im pretty sure thats the problem.

Comment: That would do it. Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that this version of MySQL  5.7.x on ubuntu 16.04 is compiled using editline library not readline - Im pretty sure thats the problem.